# How to open a terminal window in php

Tags: php, awk

I need to extract some data form a .log file. I'm doing this with awk and it works fine - but now I want to save awk results into a variable. I need to open a terminal window via php and do this command in order to get what I need:

```
cat apache_access.log | awk '{print $1}'
```

But I don't know how to do this. Can anybody tell me how to open a connection to php and how to save the result of this command in a variable?

Comment: Is this helpful at all? https://github.com/Spudley/ApacheLogIterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

Example:

```
<?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Comment: could you explain this to me in more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use php to parse logs, you need to execute command and get its output.

You can use http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php or use more human friendly library(wrapper) for that function from symfony - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: i still doesnt understand how to i write my terminal command in php :/ could you explain this to me in a more detail way?

Comment: You do not need to write smth to a terminal with php, you need to execute command (run a new process that executes command and get command output). See second link for better understanding, it do same thing with `ls` command. Symfony library is just a wrapper for `proc_open` function